# netlogo changing colors after X days

Tags: netlogo

I have three issues (full code at the end):

**ISSUE #1:**

in "change-color" section usage of elseif vs two if statement yields two different results.

```
to change-color


ask n-of 1 turtles with [not(recently-changed?)]  [
  ifelse (color = white)
    [set color  red
    set recently-changed? true]

  [set color  white
  set recently-changed? true]
]
end
```

vs

```
    to change-color
    
ask n-of 1 turtles with [not(recently-changed?)]    [ 
    
    if (color = white) 
    [set color  red 
set recently-changed? true]
    
    if (color = red) 
    [set color  white 
set recently-changed? true] 
    
    ] 
    end
```

shouldn't both of these yield the same result? But the one that uses ifelse results what I want.

To be specific, I want to ask 1 out of 5 total turtles to change color. If the the turtle color is red it changes to white and if it is white then the color changes to red. This is exactly what I get when I use elseif.

However when I use two if statements, for whatever reason Netlogo first ensures that all the red turtles become white.

**ISSUE #2:**

If the color of a turtle was recently changed then I don't want it to be changed for 3 days

```
to change-after
  ask turtles with [recently-changed?]
  [set shape "circle"
    let t3 0
    set t3 t3 + 1
    if t3 >= 3
    [set recently-changed? false
  set shape "arrow"]
  ]
end
```

but it looks like this will allow color change after 2 days. Why?

**ISSUE #3:**

I want recently changed to change shape to circle and after 3 days I want them to change back to arrow shape. But as the simulation progresses, everyone changes into a circle and nobody seems to revert back to arrow shape like intended. Why?

**FULL CODE:**

```
turtles-own
[
  recently-changed?
]


to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks

  create-turtles 10
  [
  set color red
  setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
  set recently-changed? false
  ask n-of 5 turtles [set color white]
  ]



end



to go
  change-color
  change-after
  tick
end



to change-color


  ask n-of 1 turtles with [not(recently-changed?)]
  [
  ifelse (color = white)
    [set color  red
    set recently-changed? true]

  ;if (color = red)
  [set color  white
  set recently-changed? true
  ]
]
end



to change-after
  ask turtles with [recently-changed?]
  [set shape "circle"
    let t3 0
    set t3 t3 + 1
    if t3 >= 3
    [set recently-changed? false
  set shape "arrow"]
  ]
end
```

WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO:

1. each tick I ask a turtle (whose color was not "recently changed") to change color. If turtle is white, it becomes red and vice versa.
2. If the turtle has changed color then it is marked as "recently changed" for 3 ticks and during those ticks its shape is a circle.
3. After 3 days "recently changed" phase is over and the turtle reverts back to arrow shape. Also now it can change color again and when it does it is once again marked as "recently changed" and the whole process repeats.

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario with the two if statements, you first pick out a turtle that has not recently been changed. You check if it is white and if it is, you ask it to become red. Then you check if it is red and ask it to become white.
The problem here is that the two if statements are completed after eachother so the initially white turtle that is changed to red will change back to white again. I suggest you just stick with the ifelse here.
If you still want to use `if` statements, you can include the `stop` primitive to immediately exit the enclosing procedure once you have changed a color:

```
ask n-of 1 turtles with [not(recently-changed?)]    [ 
    
    if (color = white) 
    [set color  red 
set recently-changed? true
    stop]
    
    if (color = red) 
    [set color  white 
set recently-changed? true] 
    
    ]
```

On to your question about the shapes. In the change-after procedure, you are creating a local variable called t3 with the value 0 and increasing its value with 1. The problem is that local variables cease to exist as soon as the procedure they are in ends. They are not meant to be used over multiple ticks. Instead, you should make it a turtles variable

```
turtles-own
[
  recently-changed?
  t3
]
```

Then you set `t3` to 0 within the color change procedure (I moved both that and the change to `recently-changed?` outside of the ifelse command blocks since it happens regardless of which option is chosen)

```
ask n-of 1 turtles with [not(recently-changed?)]
  [
    ifelse (color = white)
    [set color  red] [set color  white]
    
    set recently-changed? true
    set t3 0  
]
```

And then finally count up in the change-after procedure

```
to change-after
  ask turtles with [recently-changed?]
  [set shape "circle"
    set t3 t3 + 1
    if t3 >= 3
    [set recently-changed? false
  set shape "default"]
  ]
end
```

Another problem I spotted with your code is in the setup procedure. I noticed that the number of white and red turtles doesn't seem to be as intended. The problem is in this piece of code:

```
  create-turtles 10
  [
  set color red
  setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
  set recently-changed? false
  ask n-of 5 turtles [set color white]
  ]
```

You are creating 10 turtles and giving each one of them the command to change the color of 5 random turtles to white, so that command is carried out 10 times. Instead, just put the command outside the brackets

```
  create-turtles 10
  [
  set color red
  setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
  set recently-changed? false
  ]

  ask n-of 5 turtles [set color white]
```

As a last tip: I see you are using `n-of 1` a few times. You could also use  `one-of` there.

Comment: thank you so much for such a through answer. If you don't mind I have two questions:  

1........ Why does initializing t3 to 0 using "set t3 0" in "change-after" not allow changing of shape whereas having it under "change-color" like you did works?

2......... I need to make use of two IFs because I want to extend this to more colors so IFELSE will not do later but again thank you for educating me. I also noticed that should I need to use the stop command, I should move "set t3 0" at the beginning...otherwise it doesn't run and shape changes eventually stop happening.

Comment: You're welcome. As for your followup questions: 1... For two different reasons. The first was that you created it as a local variable (using `let`) which means the variable stops existing as soon as `change-after` is completed once and is created again the next time ayou call `change-after`. The second reason it doesn't work there, even when you have them stored as turtle variables, and use `set t3 0` instead, is that every time you use the `change-after` procedure you set them back to 0, then add 1, then check if they are above 3. Next round you again set it to 0, add 1, etc...

Comment: And yeah, when using a `stop` anywhere in your code it is very important to see exactly where you put it, since nothing after it gets run. You could also do more lists by making a set of nested  `ifelse` 's. That would look something like `ifelse a? [do 1] [ifelse b? [do 2] [ifelse c? [do 3] [do 4]]]` but I personally prefer a set of `if`'s with a stop added to them

Comment: I will have to correct myself about my last comment. I just found out that netlogo allows evaluating multiple conditions with a single ifelse by using parentheses, so you don't have to nest them all:
`(ifelse a? [do 1] b? [do 2] c? [do 3] [do 4])`
This can also be found in the netlogo dictionary under ifelse https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#ifelse